# How do I delete a Discipline in EPF Composer 1.5?

Tags: eclipse, agile-processes

I'm making a method combining Scrum with the OpenUP lifecycle and deliverables. I also want to keep the OpenUP disciplines apart from "Project Management".  I can "hide" it so that it's not immediately obvious in my generated method site. But when you then navigate to the "Risk List" artefact for example the PM is still seen as contributing, and if you click on the link, you get taken to the PM Discipline page.

How can I remove it completely from my method without deleting it from the OpenUP library which I'm consuming?

Comment: I don't know what OpenUP is, but is this going to be a rich client tooling?

Comment: @panny: http://www.eclipse.org/epf/downloads/downloads.php

Comment: Now the oldest and highest upvoted **unanswered** question on SO btw

Comment: I would like to be sure to understand what the issue is. Do you wan't a simple way to prevent users to access to the PM part of the method? In this case, does a `redirect` could be the answer? Sorry if I'm spaced out.

Comment: Is it okay to refer the answerer of this question as the Chuck Norris of SO?

Comment: @Code Enthusiastic The accepted answerer you mean?? No please!, just in case I get to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used EPF Composer.

I did a little bit of google searches and I understand what you are looking for can be done through Configurations (select OpenUP in your Library view) and published View definitions.

See slide 83 and 84 of this PPT document. You should be able to take it from there.

[An Introduction to the Eclipse Process Framework](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22epf%20composer%22%20%22standard%20categories%22&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CFoQFjAI&url=http://www.mountainview-itsm.com/Mountainview/downloads/An_Introduction_to_EPF.ppt&ei=p9tVUfTwD4-i8gTFroEY&usg=AFQjCNGlAoGW_ujO2uRyTa_h9jYwJq2YfA).

In case the link does not work, I searched for "EPF Composer" "Standard categories" on google and the document is at the bottom of the first results page.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks @only you.  Unfortunately I'm not on the project where I can try this out any more.  however, I've accepted your answer due to the number of upvotes and bounty awarded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To those who are to lazy [to search and browse slides](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwiUr9P6prjJAhVM2RoKHeQ7AWgQFgg0MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mountainview-itsm.com%2Fitil-training%2Fdownloads%2FAn_Introduction_to_EPF.ppt&usg=AFQjCNHCNYUI70q5JaQKxZbpqMtdUIAu_w&cad=rja):

Slide 83:
Select sub-set of method library for publishing to HTML or exporting to MS. Use “Content” selections for course grain (Plug-in and package level) configuration.  Use “Add/Subtract these Categories” for fine grain (element level) configuration.

[image]

Slide 84:
Categories group related elements
Views defined by selecting Categories
[image]